# PHP CodeIgniter query error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is my controller:

```
$isExist = $this->Sales_assistant_model->isUserExist($isUser);
$isUserExistInC_user = $this->Sales_assistant_model->checkCuserIs($sdata['email'], $bizId);

if ($isUserExistInC_user == 0) {
    //If user in the C-user table
    $isAlreadyRegistered = $this->Sales_assistant_model->checkUserEmailInC_user($sdata['email']);
    if ($isAlreadyRegistered > 0) {
        $businessName = $this->Sales_assistant_model->getBizName($bizId);
        $roleName = $this->Sales_assistant_model->getUserRolesByRoleId($sdata['corporate_user_role_role_id']);
        $username = $this->Sales_assistant_model->get_C_userNameByEmail($sdata['email']);
        $to = $sdata['email'];
        $subject = "New Business Role in".$businessName;
        $body = "<b>Dear ".$username.",</b> You Have assigned as a ".$roleName." <br> in ".$businessName."<br /> Please Login with " . base_url();
        //$this->Email_model->sendEmail($body, $to, "-", $subject);
        $res = 1;
    } else {
        if ($isExist == 0) {
            $res = $this->Sales_assistant_model->adduser($sdata);
            $to = $isUser['email'];
            $subject = "Confirm Registration";
            $body = "<b>Dear ,</b> Please click here to confirm your registration . <br>
            " . base_url() . "registration/registration?email=" . $isUser['email'] . "&code=" . $invtCode;
            //$this->Email_model->sendEmail($body, $to, "-", $subject);
        } else {
            $status = 2;
            $res_update = $this->Sales_assistant_model->updateUser_invite_rejectUser($sdata['email'], $bizId, $status);
            $res = $this->Sales_assistant_model->adduser($sdata);
            $to = $isUser['email'];
            $subject = "Confirm Registration";
            $body = "<b>Dear ,</b> Please click here to confirm your registration . <br>
            " . base_url() . "registration/registration?email=" . $isUser['email'] . "&code=" . $invtCode;
            //$this->Email_model->sendEmail($body, $to, "-", $subject);
        }
    }
} else {
    $res = 0;
}
```

These are my model functions:

```
public function checkUserEmailInC_user($email) {
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->select('COUNT(email) AS email');
    $this->db->from('corporate_user');
    $this->db->where('email',$email);
    $this->db->where('status','1');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $row = $query->row();
        $count = $row->email;
        $count = 1;
    } else {
        $count = 0;
    }

    return $count;
}

public function get_C_userNameByEmail($email) {
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->select('cuser_name');
    $this->db->from('corporate_user');
    $this->db->where('email',$email);
    $this->db->where('status','1');

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $row = $query->row();
        $count = $row->cuser_name;
    }

    return true;
}
```

If comment the line

```
$isAlreadyRegistered = $this->Sales_assistant_model->checkUserEmailInC_user($sdata['email']);
```

the inner `if` condtion works. What is the error with that function?

For example, if I assign `0` for the `$isAlreadyRegistered` then the inner `if` condition works.

I want to know why this kind of issue happens?

Comment: 1. Why do you use $this->db->trans_start();? I ask because it's important that you read up on what it is and how to use it... 2. Why does your 2nd model method return True? Is that what you actually intended?

Comment: Your return true in second model function should be return false.

Comment: You also do not have trans_complete any where http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html#managing-errors

Comment: Not sure what block of code you mean by "inner `if` condition". Is it `if ($isExist == 0) {` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has many problems.

As the comment asks "Why do you use $this->db->trans_start();?" You do not need transactions in these statements. Transactions only apply to "write" type queries like insert and update. Remove `$this->db->trans_start();` from your model methods.

Your repeat yourself a lot in your code. Practice the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle. There is much repetition in your model methods.

The model method `get_C_userNameByEmail($email)` should return a user name. Instead it ALWAYS returns TRUE.

Here are revised methods for `Sales_assistant_model`

`checkUserEmailInC_user($email)` should return a boolean. Note how the protected function `runQuery($email)` is used to DRY out the code.

```
public function checkUserEmailInC_user($email)
{
    $this->db->select('email');
    $query = $this->runQuery($email);

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return TRUE;  
    }
    //when an "if" block has a "return;", then there is no need for an "else" block 
    return FALSE;
}
```

The next method should return the user name. But if no record is found then it must return something else. NULL is a good choice because it is easy to check for.

```
public function get_C_userNameByEmail($email)
{
    $this->db->select('cuser_name');
    $query = $this->runQuery($email);

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query->row()->cuser_name;
    }

    return NULL; //no user name found, send back nothing
}
```

The next method has lines of code that can be used by other methods. Helps keep the model code DRY. The method returns a `CI_DB_result` instance documented [HERE](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html?highlight=ci_db_result#CI_DB_result). Note that the other model methods call `$this->db->select('some_column');` before calling `runQuery()`.

```
protected function runQuery($email)
{
    return $this->db
        ->from('corporate_user')
        ->where('email', $email)
        ->where('status', '1')
        ->get();
}
```

I strongly recommend that you revise the model methods `isUserExist()` and `checkCuserIs()` to return the `boolean` data type instead of integers. Then use a strict (`===`) comparison operator.

Now to your controller.

Change

```
if ($isAlreadyRegistered > 0) {
```

to

```
if ($isAlreadyRegistered === TRUE) {
```